# Custom table of contents in Pandoc-created PDF

Tags: pandoc

I'm creating PDFs from markdown files and would like to customize the output. Specifically, I'd like to change the title of the table of contents in the resulting PDF.

Currently, it's "Contents":

[image: toc_example]

How can I change that title?

---

I'm calling Pandoc 2.7.2 on Arch Linux 5.1.2 like this:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex --toc test.md -o doc.pdf
```

For completeness, this is `test.md`:

```
# First Heading
Some text

# Second Heading
More text

# Third Heading
Even more text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## with `-V toc-title:"Custom text"`

Having a look at the template at `/usr/share/pandoc/data/templates/default.latex`, there's this part:

```
$if(toc)$
$if(toc-title)$
\renewcommand*\contentsname{$toc-title$}
$endif$
```

This suggests that we can pass a parameter `toc-title` to Pandoc:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex --toc test.md -V toc-title:"Custom text" -o doc.pdf
```

And indeed, the title of the table of contents has changed:

[image: toc_with_custom_text]

For more on modifying the templates, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591517/pandoc-inserting-pages-before-generated-table-of-contents) and [the documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates).

---

To change also the abstract title from "Abstract" to something else, you can insert

```
header-includes:
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Different abstract title}
```

in the file's [metadata block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block). This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954546/how-to-translate-title-of-abstract-in-a-pandocs-markdown-e-g-rmd-document#47954817).